# Revalue local variable in python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm java script programmer and start to learn python. I try to revalue local variable in python function. My code :

```
def first_function():
    var1 = 5
    def second_function():
        var1 = 10
    second_function()
    print(var1)

first_function()
```

result this code is

```
5
```

but when second_function executed, var1 revalued with '10'. I search in google and find 'global' solution.
How can I solve this issue without define global variable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) to have an inner function's name refer to a name in an outer function.

```
def first_function():
    var1 = 5
    def second_function():
        nonlocal var1
        var1 = 10
    second_function()
    print(var1)

first_function()
```

This is the inner function equivalent to the [`global` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/simple_stmts.html#global).

As with `global`, you only need `nonlocal` if you want to assign to the name. You can access the name just fine without `nonlocal` (just like you can access global names, such as `print`, without `global`).